# Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I have an HTML form in a JSP file in my `WebContent/jsps` folder. I have a servlet class `servlet.java` in my default package in `src` folder. In my `web.xml` it is mapped as `/servlet`.

I have tried several URLs in `action` attribute of the HTML form:

```html
<form action="/servlet">
```

```html
<form action="/servlet.java">
```

```html
<form action="/src/servlet.java">
```

```html
<form action="../servlet.java">
```

But none of those work. They all keep returning a HTTP 404 error like below in Tomcat 6/7/8:

> #### HTTP Status 404 — /servlet
>
> *Description*: The requested resource (/servlet) is not available.

Or as below in Tomcat 8.5/9:

> #### HTTP Status 404 — Not Found
>
> *Message*: /servlet
>
> *Description*: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Or as below in Tomcat 10:

> #### HTTP Status 404 — Not Found
>
> *Type*: Status Report
>
> *Message*: The requested resource (/servlet) is not available
>
> *Description*: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 165):

## Introduction

This can have a lot of causes which are broken down in following sections:

- Put servlet class in a `package`
- Set servlet URL in `url-pattern`
- `@WebServlet` works only on Servlet 3.0 or newer
- `javax.servlet.*` doesn't work anymore in Servlet 5.0 or newer
- Make sure compiled `*.class` file is present in built WAR
- Test the servlet individually without any JSP/HTML page
- Use domain-relative URL to reference servlet from HTML
- Use straight quotes in HTML attributes

### Put servlet class in a `package`

First of all, put the servlet class in a Java `package`. You should *always* put publicly reuseable Java classes in a package, otherwise they are invisible to classes which are in a package, such as the source code of the server itself. This way you eliminate potential environment-specific problems. Packageless servlets work only in specific Tomcat+JDK combinations and this should never be relied upon. In case you are clueless which package to pick, start with `com.example`.

In case of a Maven flavored project, the class needs to be placed in its package structure inside `main/java` and thus *not* `main/resources`, [this is for non-class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051494/how-to-link-a-css-resource-file-in-main-resources-in-jsp/) and absolutely also *not* `main/webapp`, this is for web files. Below is an example of the folder structure of a default Maven webapp project:

```
YourProjectName
 |-- src
 |    `-- main
 |         |-- java
 |         |    `-- com
 |         |         `-- example
 |         |              `-- YourServlet.java
 |         |-- resources
 |         `-- webapp
 |              |-- WEB-INF
 |              |    `-- web.xml
 |              `-- jsps
 |                   `-- page.jsp
 :
```

Note that the `/jsps` subfolder is not strictly necessary. You can even do without it and put the JSP file directly in `/webapp` root, but I'm just taking over this from your question.

### Set servlet URL in `url-pattern`

The servlet URL is specified as the "URL pattern" of the servlet mapping. It's absolutely not per definition the classname/filename of the servlet class. The URL pattern is to be specified as value of `@WebServlet` annotation.

```
package com.example; // Use a package!

import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; // or javax.*
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet; // or javax.*

@WebServlet("/servlet") // This is the URL of the servlet.
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet { // Must be public and extend HttpServlet.
    // ...
}
```

In case you want to support path parameters like `/servlet/foo/bar`, then use an URL pattern of `/servlet/*` instead. See also [Servlet and path parameters like /xyz/{value}/test, how to map in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715474/servlet-and-path-parameters-like-xyz-value-test-how-to-map-in-web-xml)

Do note that it's considered a bad practice to use a Servlet URL pattern of `/*` or `/` in an attempt to have a "front controller". So do not abuse these URL patterns in an attempt to try to catch all URLs. For an in depth explanation see also [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern).

### `@WebServlet` works only on Servlet 3.0 or newer

In order to use `@WebServlet`, you need to make sure that your `web.xml` file, if any (it's optional since Servlet 3.0), is declared conform Servlet 3.0+ version [and thus *not* conform e.g. 2.5 version or lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat-7). It should absolutely also not have any `<!DOCTYPE>` line. Below is a Servlet 6.0 compatible one (which matches Tomcat 10.1+, WildFly 27+ (Preview), GlassFish/Payara 7+, etc) in its entirety:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_6_0.xsd"
    version="6.0"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

And below is a Servlet 5.0 compatible one (which matches Tomcat 10.0+, WildFly 22+ (Preview), GlassFish/Payara 6+, etc).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
    version="5.0"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

And below is a Servlet 4.0 compatible one (which matches Tomcat 9+, WildFly 11+, GlassFish/Payara 5+, etc).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0"
>
    <!-- Config here. -->
</web-app>
```

Or, in case you're not on Servlet 3.0+ yet (e.g. Tomcat 6 or older), then remove the `@WebServlet` annotation (and make sure you also remove all the wrong JAR files or Maven dependencies which incorrectly made it possible for you to successfully compile the code):

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

And register the servlet instead in `web.xml` like this:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class> <!-- Including the package thus -->
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>  <!-- This is the URL of the servlet. -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note thus that you should **not** use *both* ways. Use *either* annotation based configuarion *or* XML based configuration. When you have both, then XML based configuration will override annotation based configuration.

### `javax.servlet.*` doesn't work anymore in Servlet 5.0 or newer

Since Jakarta EE 9 / Servlet 5.0 (Tomcat 10, TomEE 9, WildFly 22 Preview, GlassFish 6, Payara 6, Liberty 22, etc), the `javax.*` package has been renamed to `jakarta.*` package.

In other words, please make absolutely sure that you don't randomly put JAR files of a different server in your WAR project such as tomcat-servlet-api.jar merely in order to get the `javax.*` package to compile. This will only cause trouble. Remove them altogether and edit the imports of your servlet class from

```java
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

to

```java
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
```

In case you're using Maven, you can find examples of proper `pom.xml` declarations for Tomcat 10+, Tomcat 9-, JEE 9+ and JEE 8- in this answer: [How to properly configure Jakarta EE libraries in Maven pom.xml for Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65703840/how-to-properly-configure-jakarta-ee-libraries-in-maven-pom-xml-for-tomcat/65704617#65704617) The alternative is to downgrade the server to an older version, e.g. from Tomcat 10 back to Tomcat 9 or older, but this is clearly not the recommended way to go.

In case you're using Spring instead of Jakarta EE, Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3 are the first versions to target Servlet 5.0 and therefore also the first versions to use the `jakarta.*` package. Older versions still use the `javax.*` package. Adjust your imports accordingly.

You need to make absolutely sure that you don't have any conflicting libraries in your dependencies (either the pom.xml or the physical files in /WEB-INF/lib) which incorrectly make it possible to still successfully compile against `javax.servlet.*`. Using `javax.servlet.*` must give a compilation error in projects targeted at at least Servlet 5.0+ (so, either Jakarta EE 9+ or Spring 6+ or Spring Boot 3+).

### Make sure compiled `*.class` file is present in built WAR

In case you're using a build tool such as Eclipse and/or Maven, then you need to make absolutely sure that the compiled servlet class file resides in its package structure in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the produced WAR file. In case of `package com.example; public class YourServlet`, it must be located in `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/YourServlet.class`. Otherwise you will face in case of `@WebServlet` also a 404 error, or in case of `<servlet>` a HTTP 500 error like below:

> ## HTTP Status 500
>
> Error instantiating servlet class com.example.YourServlet

And find in the server log a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.YourServlet`, followed by a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.YourServlet`, in turn followed by `jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.example.YourServlet`.

An easy way to verify if the servlet is correctly compiled and placed in classpath is to let the build tool produce a WAR file (e.g. rightclick project, *Export > WAR file* in Eclipse) and then inspect its contents with a ZIP tool. If the servlet class is missing in `/WEB-INF/classes`, or if the export causes an error, then the project is badly configured or some IDE/project configuration defaults have been mistakenly reverted (e.g. *Project > Build Automatically* has been disabled in Eclipse).

You also need to make sure that the project icon has no red cross indicating a build error. You can find the exact error in *Problems*  view (*Window > Show View > Other...*). Usually the error message is fine Googlable. In case you have no clue, best is to restart from scratch and do not touch any IDE/project configuration defaults. In case you're using Eclipse, you can find instructions in [How do I import the javax.servlet / jakarta.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

### Test the servlet individually without any JSP/HTML page

Provided that the server runs on `localhost:8080`, and that the WAR is successfully deployed on a context path of `/contextname` (which defaults to the IDE project name or the Maven build artifact file name, case sensitive!), and the servlet hasn't failed its initialization (read server logs for any deploy/servlet success/fail messages and the actual context path and servlet mapping), then a servlet with URL pattern of `/servlet` is available at `http://localhost:8080/contextname/servlet`.

You can just enter it straight in browser's address bar to test it invidivually. If its `doGet()` is properly overriden and implemented, then you will see its output in browser. Or if you don't have any `doGet()` or if it incorrectly calls `super.doGet()`, then a "[HTTP 405: HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370633/405-http-method-get-is-not-supported-by-this-url)" error will be shown (which is still better than a 404 as a 405 is evidence that the servlet itself is actually found).

Overriding `service()` is a bad practice, unless you're reinventing a MVC framework — which is very unlikely if you're just starting out with servlets and are clueless as to the problem described in the current question. See also [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications).

Note that when the servlet already returns 404 when tested invidivually, then it's entirely pointless to try with a HTML form instead. Logically, it's therefore also entirely pointless to include any HTML form in questions about 404 errors from a servlet.

### Use domain-relative URL to reference servlet from HTML

Once you've verified that the servlet works fine when invoked individually, then you can advance to HTML. As to your concrete problem with the HTML form, the `<form action>` value needs to be a valid URL. The same applies to `<a href>`, `<img src>`, `<script src>`, etc. You need to understand how absolute/relative URLs work. You know, an URL is a web address as you can enter/see in the webbrowser's address bar. If you're specifying a relative URL as form action, i.e. without the `http://` scheme, then it becomes relative to the *current* URL as you see in your webbrowser's address bar. It's thus absolutely not relative to the JSP/HTML file location in server's WAR folder structure as many starters seem to think.

So, assuming that the JSP page with the HTML form is opened by `http://localhost:8080/contextname/jsps/page.jsp` (and thus **not** by `file://...`), and you need to submit to a servlet located in `http://localhost:8080/contextname/servlet`, here are several cases (note that you can here safely substitute `<form action>` with `<a href>`, `<img src>`, `<script src>`, etc):

- Form action submits to an URL with a leading slash.

  ```html
    <form action="/servlet">
  ```

  The leading slash `/` makes the URL relative to the domain, thus the form will submit to

  ```
    http://localhost:8080/servlet
  ```

  But this will likely result in a 404 as it's in the wrong context.

  ---
- Form action submits to an URL without a leading slash.

  ```html
    <form action="servlet">
  ```

  This makes the URL relative to the current folder of the current URL, thus the form will submit to

  ```
    http://localhost:8080/contextname/jsps/servlet
  ```

  But this will likely result in a 404 as it's in the wrong folder.

  ---
- Form action submits to an URL which goes one folder up.

  ```html
    <form action="../servlet">
  ```

  This will go one folder up (exactly like as in local disk file system paths!), thus the form will submit to

  ```
    http://localhost:8080/contextname/servlet
  ```

  This one must work!

  ---
- The canonical approach, however, is to make the URL domain-relative so that you don't need to fix the URLs once again when you happen to move the JSP files around into another folder.

  ```html
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/servlet">
  ```

  This will generate

  ```html
    <form action="/contextname/servlet">
  ```

  Which will thus always submit to the right URL.

  ---

### Use straight quotes in HTML attributes

You need to make absolutely sure you're using straight quotes in HTML attributes like `action="..."` or `action='...'` and thus *not* curly quotes like `action=”...”` or `action=’...’`. Curly quotes are not supported in HTML and they will simply become part of the value. Watch out when copy-pasting code snippets from blogs! Some blog engines, notably Wordpress, are known to by default use so-called "smart quotes" which thus also corrupts the quotes in code snippets this way. On the other hand, instead of copy-pasting code, try simply typing over the code yourself. Additional advantage of actually getting the code through your brain and fingers is that it will make you to remember and understand the code much better in long term and also make you a better developer.

### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - Contains some hello world examples
- [How to call servlet class from HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395251/how-to-call-servlet-class-from-html-file)
- [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)
- [How do I pass current item to Java method by clicking a hyperlink or button in JSP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078701/how-do-i-pass-current-item-to-java-method-by-clicking-a-hyperlink-or-button-in-j)

#### Other cases of HTTP Status 404 error:

- [HTTP Status 404 - Servlet [ServletName] is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293325)
- [HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/ProjectName/) is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798953)
- [HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource (/) is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520267)
- [JSP in /WEB-INF returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386031)
- [Referencing a resource placed in WEB-INF folder in JSP file returns HTTP 404 on resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752246)
- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I was incorrectly creating the war file using jar command. When i created the war from eclipse directly my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 5):

**Scenario #1:** You **accidentially re-deployed** from the command line while tomcat was **already running**.

**Short Answer:** Stop Tomcat, **delete target folder**, mvn package, then re-deploy

---

**Scenario #2:** request.getRequestDispatcher("**MIS_SPELLED_FILE_NAME**.jsp")

**Short Answer:** Check file name **spelling**, make sure **case** is correct.

---

**Scenario #3: Class Not Found Exceptions**
(Answer put here because: Question# 17982240  )
([java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for servlet in tomcat with eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982240) )
(was marked as duplicate and directed me here )

Short Answer #3.1: web.xml has wrong package path in servlet-class tag.

Short Answer #3.2: java file has wrong import statement.

---

### Below is further details for Scenario #1:

---

1: Stop Tomcat

- Option 1: Via CTRL+C in terminal.
- Option 2: (terminal closed while tomcat still running)
- ------------ 2.1: press:**Windows+R** --> type:"**services.msc**"
- ------------ 2.2: Find "Apache Tomcat #.# Tomcat#" in Name column of list.
- ------------ 2.3: Right Click --> "**stop**"

2: Delete the "target" folder.
**(mvn clean will not help you here)**

3: mvn package

4: *YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_COMMAND_HERE*

(Mine: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 5190 target/*.war )

**Full Back Story:**

---

Accidentially opened a new git-bash window and
tried to deploy a .war file for my heroku project via:

java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port 5190 target/*.war

After a failure to deploy, I realized I had two git-bash windows open,
and **had not used CTLR+C to stop the previous deployment**.

I was met with:

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report
>
> Message /if-student-test.jsp
>
> Description The origin server  did not find a current representation
>   for  the target resource or is not willing  to disclose that one
>   exists.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.31

### Below is further details for Scenario #3:

---

SCENARIO 3.1:
   The servlet-class package path is wrong 
   in your web.xml file.

It should MATCH the package statement at top
   of your java servlet class.

File: my_stuff/**MyClass.java**:

```
   package my_stuff;
```

File: PRJ_ROOT/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/**web.xml**

```
   <servlet-class>
   my_stuff.MyClass
   </servlet-class>
```

SCENARIO 3.2:

You put the wrong "**package**" statement
   at top of your myClass.java file.

For example:

File is in: "**/my_stuff**" folder

You mistakenly write:

```
package com.my_stuff
```

This is tricky because:

1: The maven build (mvn package) will not report any errors here.

2: servlet-class line in web.xml can have CORRECT package path. E.g:

```
<servlet-class>
my_stuff.MyClass
</servlet-class>
```

---

Stack Used:
**Notepad++** + **GitBash** + **Maven** + **Heroku Web App Runner** + **Tomcat9** + **Windows10**:

Comment: Your AppName.war and thus the exploded folder name doesn't match your expected name, for example when your war file is versioned like AppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war and you're trying /AppName/.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have entered the correct URL Mapping as specified in the Web.xml

For example:

In the web.xml, your servlet declaration maybe:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ControllerA</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>PackageName.ControllerA</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerA</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/theController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

What this snippet does is `<url-pattern>/theController</url-pattern>`will set the name that will be used to call the servlet from the front end (eg: form) through the URL. Therefore when you reference the servlet in the front end, in order to ensure that the request goes to the servlet "ControllerA", it should refer the specified URL Pattern "theController" from the form.

eg:

```
<form action="theController" method="POST">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using IntelliJ, this is what fixed it for me:

Go to the Tomcat configuration:
[image]

Configuration > Deployment Tab
[image]

Scroll down and add `/` to the Application Context dropdown
[image]

Answer (score 1):

An old thread, but since I didn't find it elsewhere, here is one more possibility:

If you're using **servlet-api 3.0+**, then your web.xml must **NOT** include `metadata-complete="true"` attribute

[image]

This tells tomcat to map the servlets using data given in `web.xml` instead of using the `@WebServlet` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for `HTTP Status 404` in NetBeans IDE:
Right click on your project and go to your project properties, then click on run, then input your project relative URL like `index.jsp`.

1. Project->Properties
2. Click on Run
3. Relative URL:/index.jsp (Select your project root URL)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my method was missing the @RequestBody annotation. After adding the annotation I no longer received the 404 exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following two steps. I hope, it will solve the "404 not found" issue in tomcat server during the development of java servlet application.

Step 1: `Right click on the server(in the server explorer tab)->Properties->Switch Location from workspace metadata to tomcat server`

Step 2: `Double Click on the server(in the server explorer tab)->Select Use tomcat installation option inside server location menu`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the old web library such that are spring framework libraries. And build a new path of the libraries. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run your IDE as Admin. After that, right click the project folder -> Project Facets and make sure that the Java Version is set correct. On my PC. (For Example 1.8) Now it should work.

Don't just start your server, for example Wildfly, using the cmd. It has to be launched within the IDE and now visit your localhost URL. Example: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

The fix that worked for me is(if you are using Maven): Rightclick your project, Maven -> Update project. This might give you some other error with the JDK and other Libraries(in my case, MySQL connector), but once you fix them, your original problem should be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to open a servlet with javascript without using 'form' and 'submit' button, here is the following code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("<<button-id>>");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.href= "<<full-servlet-path>>" (eg. http://localhost:8086/xyz/servlet)
});
```

Key:

1) button-id : The 'id' tag you give to your button in your html/jsp file.

2) full-servlet-path: The path that shows in the browser when you run the servlet alone

Answer (score 0):

Mapping in web.xml is what i have done :-

1. If there's another package made for new program then we must mention :-

packagename.filename between opening and closing of servlet-class tag in xml file.

2. If you are mapping your files in xml and they are not working or showing errors , then comment on the annotation line of code in the respective files.

Both methods dont work with one another , so either i use annotation method of files mentioned when we create servlet or the way of mapping , then i delete or comment the annotation line. Eg:

```
 <servlet>
   <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>performance.FirstServ</servlet-class>
   </servlet>    
   
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>s1</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/FirstServ</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>performance.SecondServ</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/SecondServ</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

---

Commenting the annotation line of code in the respective file,if mapping in xml is done.

```
//@WebServlet("/FirstServ")
//@WebServlet("/SecondServ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is here who is using MySQL and felt that the code was working the previous day and now it doesn't, then I guess you must open MySQL CLI or MySQL Workbench and just make the connection to the database once. Once it gets connected, then the database also gets connected to the Java Application. I used to get the Hibernate Dialect error stating something wrong with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. I think MySQL in some computers has a startup problem. This solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student and new to Java there might be some issue going on with your web.xml file.

> 1. Try removing the web.xml file.
> 2. Secondly check that your path variables are properly  set or not.
> 3. Restart tomcat server Or your PC.

Your problem will be surely solved.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue too, I was receiving a 404 when accessing a URL pattern that I knew was linked to a Servlet. The reason is because I had 2 Servlets with their @WebServlet `name` parameter set as the same string.

```java
@WebServlet(name = "ServletName", urlPatterns = {"/path"})
public class ServletName extends HttpServlet {}
```

```java
@WebServlet(name = "ServletName", urlPatterns = {"/other-path"})
public class OtherServletName extends HttpServlet {}
```

Both of the `name` parameters are the same. If you're using the name parameter, make sure they are unique compared to all other Servlets on your application.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Tried all of this but didn't help. I managed to solve this issue by adding element tags to beginning and end of the xml file. ill leave my xml file below for reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<element>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
     
<servlet> 
    <servlet-name>InsertServlet</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.worklog.InsertServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>InsertServlet</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/insert</url-pattern> 
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

</element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was developing a mvc based REST API where there was no explicit html configuration or files. The API was using Swagger to generate a user interface. The problem started when I introduced Swagger version "3.0.0". I reverted back to Swagger "2.9.2" This solved my problem.

```
<!-- Swagger -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check **context root cannot be empty**.

If you're using eclipse:
**right click**, select **properties**, then **web project settings**. Check **the context root cannot be empty**