# Error 404: The requested resource is not available using HelloWorld servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am writing a Java Servlet, and I am struggling to get a simple `HelloWorld` example to work properly.

The `HelloWorld.java` class is:

```
package crunch;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

I am running Tomcat v7.0, and have already read similar questions, with responses referring to changing the `invoker` `servlet-mapping` section in `web.xml`. This section actually doesn't exist in mine, and when I added it the same problem still occurred.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11731377

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this (if the Java EE V6)

```
package crunch;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet(name="hello",urlPatterns={"/hello"}) // added this line

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

now reach the servlet by `http://127.0.0.1:8080/yourapp/hello`

where 8080 is default Tomcat port, and `yourapp` is the context name of your applciation

Comment: I can't get access in my html file, please help!!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967510/the-requested-resource-xxx-html-is-not-available-when-redirect/24967768#24967768

Answer (score 11):

You definitely need to map your servlet onto some URL. If you use Java EE 6 (that means at least Servlet API 3.0) then you can annotate your servlet like

```
@WebServlet(name="helloServlet", urlPatterns={"/hello"})
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
     //rest of the class
```

Then you can just go to the `localhost:8080/yourApp/hello` and the value should be displayed. In case you can't use Servlet 3.0 API than you need to register this servlet into `web.xml` file like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>crunch.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 7):

Writing Java servlets is easy if you use Java EE 7

```
@WebServlet("/hello-world")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response) {
   response.setContentType("text/html");
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.println("Hello World");
   out.flush();
  }
}
```

Since servlet 3.0

> The good news is the deployment descriptor is no longer required!

Read the tutorial for [Java Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets.htm#BNAFD).

Comment: The link to the Servlet tutorial changes to [http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets.htm#BNAFD](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets.htm#BNAFD)

Answer (score 2):

this is may be due to the thing that you have created your .jsp or the .html file in the **WEB-INF** instead of the **WebContent** folder.

Solution: Just replace the files that are there in the WEB-INF folder to the Webcontent folder and try executing the same - You will get the appropriate output

Answer (score 0):

For those stuck with "The requested resource is not available" in Java EE 7 and dynamic web module 3.x, maybe this could help: the "Create Servlet" wizard in Eclipse (tested in Mars) doesn't create the *@Path* annotation for the servlet class, but I had to include it to access successfuly to the public methods exposed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to user ../../projectName/Filename.jsp  in your action attr. or href

../ =  contains current folder simple(demo.project.filename.jsp)

Servlet can only be called with 1 slash forward to your project name..

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in `web.xml` file. In one `<servlet-mapping>` there was an error inside `<url-pattern>`: I forgot to add `/` before url.