# The requested resource (/xxx.html) is not available when redirect

Tags: java, html, servlets, web, path

I really do my homework to figure out why but I am still struggling. Please help!

I have a Servlet which is running well without any page before today(tomcat 7 & eclipse)

Now, I hope to try add some pages and redirect to them. I added a line of

`response.sendRedirect("/userhelp.html");`

To test if the page is working, but it is not.

I place my userhelp.html under foler of WebContent. For test, I have tried copying it into WEB-INF, neither of it works.

And If I replace "/userhelp.html" into "userhelp.html" it did not have a error page but have "recursive redirect".

Below is my code which is relative.

```
@WebServlet(name="core",urlPatterns={"/"})
public class CoreServlet extends HttpServlet {


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.sendRedirect("/userhelp.html");
```

Comment: A recursive redirect means?

Comment: Sorry, since my chrome is a Chinese verison, so I just translate it, it should means PageA-->PageA-->PageA-->PageA....something like this, because I see my tomcat is running with blank for long time with a green process bar. But I think it should work for /userhelp.html , why 404?Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your sendrederct to :

> response.sendRedirect("/ProjectName/userhelp.html");

You have response.sendRedirect("/userhelp.html");  arguement to your sendRedirect starts with a forward slash.Which means that 'realative to root of container'.So container builds URL relative to original URL of request.

Your userhelp.html page exits in your project's webcontent.It's relative path from container's root should be /Projectname/userhelp.html.So you need to edit your path in 
response.sendRedirect.

Edit : Problem is in your servlet mapping as @servletmapping(/) means that anything which comes for this url pattern(/) , should be send to this servlet.So what really happens is that when your servlet is called first time and response.sendredirect() is called ,a new request object is created and as path for it is / , So again your servlet gets called and this recursive process starts.

So solution for this is to change servlet mapping to : @servletmapping(/test) and then call this servlet by calling yourlocalhost/test/ .So when this time redirection is done , Servlet is not called for that.

Comment: this is not work for me. When I using project/userhelp.html, I got a strange situation is that, when I have log "enter doget"when enter doGet() method, and it just continue to print "enter doget" for your solution, and nothing comeout!

Comment: How you have  called your servlet?Please post your code which calls your servlet.

Comment: What do you mean, "called"  the log is printed,so the do get method is  in.

Comment: Yes it is in , but why its 'continuously' printing "enter doget"?Is your servlet being called repeatedly?If yes than I think that's the reason for it.Even you have mentioned in your question about recursive  page a .I think problem is something else

Comment: But problem is why he is repeating. If I remove this code(redirect), everything will be ok

Comment: Hey try putting a return after response.sendRedirect :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58050/discussion-between-jaskey-and-abhijeet-panwar).