# Unable to access application in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I prepared a war file of my java project called Contactus.war and placed it in webapps folder of Tomcat. I tried to access the application using the url http://localhost:8080/Contactus  I get the below error. What did I do wrong?

```
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Can you please help me . Thank you in advance

Comment: More information is necessary...what is the contents of the war? What are the contents and their names (as defined by the web.xml)?

Comment: please look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208164/tomcat-servlet-error-404-the-requested-resource-is-not-available