# In web based application I am getting 404 error while processing servlet class after login

Tags: jsp, servlets, mapping, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

I am working on small web application using jsp, java, mysql and tomcat as web application server. My **loginPage.jsp** and **index.jsp** is in WebContent folder and I will collect user information username and password in loginPage.jsp and will use action to call a **(loginservlet)** servlet class that process **(it does other stuff such as validating user and authorising)** stuff and execute a line of code as show below

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Things are ok until I see a 404 error after I entered username and password and hit submit button. It seems there is some confusion around servlet mapping or issue with where I keep my classes in project. right now i kept my servlet classes under /JavaResources/src/com.mycompany.xyz -- in xyz I have my class **LoginServlet**. Please help me with the issue on why I am getting 404 error.

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>loginPage.jsp</welcome-file></welcome-file-list>   <servlet>  
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name><servlet-class>com.mycompany.xyz.LoginServlet</servlet-class>                 </servlet>   

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
<url-patt ern>/LoginServletPath</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After entering username and password and hit submit I see 404 page with below information. Instead of showing **index.jsp** I am getting 404 error, and I am not sure why.

**type Status report**

**message /LoginServletPath**

**description The requested resource is not available.**

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. To start, which URL do you see in address bar when 404 error is shown? Which resource that couldn't be found by the server is being mentioned in the 404 error message?

Comment: I am seeing  **http://localhost:8080/LoginServletPath**. Also what is on the page I have added in my original post.

Comment: @BalusC Your answer helped me thanks.**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa**