# Issue in <img> tag in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I want to display an image in a particular  in a jsp page and I am calling servlet from the  tag but the control is never reaching the servlet. Can someone help me find the error in the logic or some syntax issue if any..?? This is the img tag of the jsp page:

```
 <img src="/controller/ImageServlet" alt="My image" height="200px" width="200px">
```

Is this the correct way to transfer the control to the servlet through img tag?
 Here "controller" is a package under which I have defined "ImageServlet" servlet.

Comment: What is the mapping for `ImageServlet` ?

Comment: You probably want `src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller/ImageServlet"`. Or, if you use the JSTL, `src="<c:url value='/controller/ImageServlet'/>"`. Also, the class name and package name are irrelevant. What matters is the mapping of the servlet.

Comment: <servlet-mapping>
 
    <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/new/WebContent/profile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>    @Berger

Comment: I have tried the former way of defining the "src" which was mentioned by you but it didn't work in my case. @JBNizet

Comment: In the future, when things appear to be failing in client side, press F12 to open the web developer's toolset. In the network monitor and console you should have noticed a HTTP 404 error (which in turn is also explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11731377)