# GlassFish HTTP Status 404 Servlet Application

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I am very new to Servlet programing. I try to print particular thing on web browser.

My project's controllers are located under com.myokg.controller folder. This is my Servlet code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddPassenger
 */
@WebServlet("/AddPassenger")
public class AddPassenger extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddPassenger() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

When I enter url as `http://localhost:8080/web1/AddPassenger` web browser shows `HTTP Status 404 - Not Found` error. Why is that? Are my routing went wrong?

**EDIT**

folder structure

[image]

I also tried [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa) this. But it's not working too

Comment: Try to replace `@WebServlet("/AddPassenger")` with `@WebServlet(name="AddPassenger", urlPatterns={"/AddPassenger"})`

Comment: it is not working.

Comment: I just edited my question and added folder structure too