# Uncummon Tomcat 404 error...Video inside

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to learn Servlet but whenever I create one I can't run it. Eclipse returns a 404 error. I read a lot of questions about it here on stackoverflow and on other websites, I've literally tried everything..

I copied the Root, manager etc.. folders on the workplace
I also created a variable in the user section of my computer called `HOME_CATALINA` with a value "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\libservlet-api.jr;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;."
and a value in the System Section called `CLASSPATH` with a value of "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\libservlet-api.jr;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;."

[image]

If I type on the browser "http://localhost:8080" I can see the TomCat webpage.
I don't know what to do anymore. I recorded a video so you'll understand:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y0q6lm7eBU&feature=youtu.be

This is Serv.java:

```
package pak;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
* Servlet implementation class Serv
*/
@WebServlet("/Serv")
public class Serv extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter prik = response.getWriter();

        prik.println("<html><body>Hello World </body></html>");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is web.xml:
       pastebin.com/NfJvz5Vh

What should I do? Help :(

Comment: Open http://localhost:8080/Serv

Comment: I still have the error

Comment: You declare /Serv twice, once within web.xml file, and once in the @WebServlet annotation. Try to leave in web.xml only <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

Comment: You incorrectly installed Tomcat as a permanent/automatic windows background service intented for production environments (exe file) instead of as a manually managed development server (zip file). The duplicate shows the correct procedure of integrating Tomcat in Eclipse. After having restarted from scratch the correct way, advance here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11731377

Comment: Sir,i don't want who you are,but i want to merry you!!!