# JSP Servlet mapping not working, keep getting 404

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Trying to learn JSP and making my first project, and I absolutely cannot get the url mapping to work. I tried mapping in web.xml at first, but that didn't work, so I upgraded to javax servlet 3.0.1 and tried the annotation mapping, but again I get a 404 error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have a simple html form with

```
<form action="Login" method="POST">
        <div align="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and a Servlet with

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //...
}
```

Can anyone please advise me on what I may be doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you deploying to a webapp?  That is, maybe you need to go to something like http://localhost:8080/someappname/login.jsp to get to the JSP.  If that is the case you'll need to include the webapp name for the servlet too.

Comment: Fix your form action to something like this: `<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Login">`.

Comment: Check the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa

Comment: Yes its a webapp, I'm using intellij to deploy the tomcat server. My app is at the root, http://localhost:8080/index.jsp. Shouldn't http://localhost:8080/Login work?

Comment: Even if i move my app context out of the root and into a directory like localhost:8080/Project/Login I still get 404

Comment: Which version of Apache Tomcat are you using?

Comment: 8.5. I think this an issuewith IntelliJ and Tomcat because I got the same code and configuration and when I deploy Tomcat with eclipse it works