# Using multiple servlets in one dynamic web project (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, web.xml

I am trying to use multiple servlets in one dynamic web project. The web.xml code is as  follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SupremeConsulting</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>PackRequired.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>PackRequired.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Note that the first servlet(login) is working fine. But the second servlet(register) keeps giving me

```
**description** The requested resource is not available.
```

How can I solve this problem? Sorry if its a stupid question but I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)