# Eclipse - Servlet only stops returning 404 after exporting to WAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm following a course and trying to create a servlet using Eclipse.

**I have tried the following scenarios:**

- JRE: 8, 10, 11
- Dynamic web module version: 3, 4
- Target runtime: Apache Tomcat v9.0

**What Happened**

In each combination of the above scenarios, these are the steps I completed: right click to create new dynamic web project --> right click to create a servlet inside a package (not the default package) --> add `response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello </h1>");` inside the doGet method --> add servlet-api.jar to build path --> Restart the server --> Run the servlet class on the server

In all scenarios, I get a 404 error as below:

> Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

In all scenarios, after I accidentally export the project into a WAR file, the error is gone and the servlet works.

I'm trying to create new projects to test my hypothesis and the same situation continues.

**Here's the complete servlet code in one of the scenarios:**

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/HelloWorld5")
public class HelloWorld5 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public HelloWorld5() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello 5</h1>");
    }

}
```

**I have checked the following question and it's not answering my question**

[Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

**Question**

Please help me understand why all my projects are not working before and will work after exporting them into WAR files.

**Updates based on comments:**

URL requested: 
http://localhost:8080/MyHelloServlet5/HelloWorld5

ContextPath: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdmd6.png)

Comment: You don't need to add `servlet-api.jar` to the Build Path, targeting the server runtime gives you those packages. What URL are you requesting that fails, and what server context (path) is your application, as a whole, set to deploy under?

Comment: @nitind Regarding the build path, I manually removed the entire tomcat package and added only the servlet-api.jar, just to be consistent with the tutorial I'm following. Even if I don't do this, I also get 404, which disappears after I export the project to a WAR. URL requested: http://localhost:8080/MyHelloServlet5/HelloWorld5
ContextPath: MyHelloServlet5

Comment: Problem is solved when I build the project properly!!!