# How does the HTML page find a servlet in an Eclipse dynamic web project?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I created a dynamic web project in Eclipse with a HTML page (in the WebContent folder of the project) that is supposed to send some input data from the user to a servlet (with the name "Tee").
I try to locate the servlet with

form method="get" action="../../src/Tee"

it does not find it.  No, its not a Status 404 error message. But simply "the page cannot be displayed."

I tried this:

form method="get" action="/Tee"

as well, does not work either.

The Tomcat server is started and the project is deployed on the server. If i start the servlet itself, it runs on the server without problem (with all the data set to null, as these are supposed to come from the html page).

Yes, there are similary questions out there but those gave no real solution to me.

[image]

Comment: What error do you get? 404?

Comment: Kein Zugriff auf Seite = "Site can't be reached"

Comment: You try to access the file, not the site (at least in eclipse)

Comment: @bebeböbe - Rename `doPost` to `doGet`. Then right-click the HTML file in Eclipse and click **Run As > Run on server**. Note that it should be `action="Tee"` and not `"/Tee"` or `"../../src/Tee"` in the HTML form. If you were using Spring MVC, any of  `"Tee"` and `"/Tee"` would have been fine.

Comment: if I try "Run on server", I get a message "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists"

Comment: @bebeböbe - Stop the server and Then right-click the HTML file in Eclipse and click **Run As > Run on server**.

Comment: thanks but on "run on server " I get the error message "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: no, its not the same question, its a different error message

Comment: It may not be exactly the same question, but the core problem and the answer is definitely the same. There's no need to copypaste the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a servlet class something like:

```
@WebServlet("/Tee")
public class Tee extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("Hello World!");
        //...
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //...
    }
}
```

After writing the servlet, right-click its name in Eclipse and click **Run As > Run  on server**

If it runs successfully in the Eclipse browser, it will be accessible in your HTML with its name e.g.

```
<form method="GET" action="Tee">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

## Update

After you posted the servlet code, I can see a problem there. You have written `method="GET"` in the HTML form but in the servlet code, you have just `doPost`. You should have `doGet` in the servlet for `method="GET"` in the HTML form to be acted on. Add the method, `doGet` in addition to `doPost` in the servlet.

Comment: Yes, I wrote such a servlet class. But the browser in Eclipse says it does not find it.

Comment: You need to deploy the project to a server e.g. Tomcat. Do you have server e.g. Tomcat available in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, I have a Tomcat server, and the project is already deployed on the server.

Comment: Is it annotated with `@WebServlet`? Is it a `.java` file? Is it in the dource directory?

Comment: To add to what @dan1st has asked, make sure your server is running.

Comment: Btw if you write `@WebServlet("Tee")`, the path will be `/Tee`, not `../../src/Tee`.

Comment: yes, it is in src.  and yes I tried also "/Tee"

Comment: yes the server is running

Comment: thanks but its still not working with "doGet" in the servlet-.

Comment: @bebeböbe - The address in the browser should be `http://localhost:8080/TeeApp/Tee` but it shows as `file:///C:...` in your screenshot which is not correct. As mentioned earlier, stop the server and Then right-click the HTML file in Eclipse and click **Run As > Run on server**.

Comment: thanks, but then it says "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: Your configurations may be wrong. Try creating a new project by following https://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/java-web-application-hello-world.html

Comment: ok, i created a new Project, I get the same error message though

Comment: @bebe: This answer is indeed incomplete. It's fully explained in the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa Unfortunately this Arvind user has removed it from your question.

Comment: its not a status 404 error message, but the browser's error page "Cannot find server". - "the page cannot be displayed."