# Web-application,I use netbeans 12.3 + Tomcat 9 + jdk 15 - > error 404

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, tomcat9

I use netbeans 12.3 and Tomcat 9 and jdk 15 and java ee 7 assembly **success** and Tomcat start **run** but when i go to any pages - > 404 error
Sorry, my english is bad. I am noob in java and i pray, please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : switch any "jdk" for "jdk 15" and just reinstall "netbeans"  to "netbeansLTS".