# Spring MVC webapp not loading on browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am new to spring mvc and tomcat.
I have developed a demo spring mvc project and trying to deploy it on tomcat 9 through eclipse.
Server starts successfully but when i try to access the url from browser i get 404 with below error message on screen. :

Message The requested resource [/spring-mvc-demo/] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Below are my code details :

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

<absolute-ordering />

<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring-mvc-demo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="main.webapp" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package main.webapp.springdemo.controller;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
 public class HomeController {

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("HomeController bean getting intiated");
}

@RequestMapping("/")
public String getMainMenu() {
    return "main-menu";
}
}
```

I tried running this app on tomcat 9 through eclipse as well as manually but in both the scenarios i got same error.

Comment: Can you reconfirm your servlet mapping?

Comment: @VeKe servlet-mapping is correct as provided in the question. Do you see any issues with it?

Comment: Can you go through this answer once https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731512/1878022

Comment: @VeKe i went through the answer you shared and noticed my war file does not have the classes folder under WEB-INF. Not sure though why my war file doesnt have class files

Comment: *I am new to spring mvc and tomcat.* Then discard your obsolete tutorial and use Spring Boot. You can completely discard your XML configuration and your Tomcat setup. [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io) will auto-generate a runnable project skeleton for you. (And I strongly recommend Thymeleaf instead of JSP; it fixes a lot of the core problems with it and is still pretty familiar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the application deploys without errors (check your logs), the URI path you are using to access it is almost certainly wrong. In a servlet environment the URI path decomposes as:

```
<context-path><servlet-path><path-info>
```

where:

- `<context-path>` is the prefix to your application. In the Eclipse server configuration page this is called just *"path"* and defaults to `/<project-name>`,
- `<servlet-path>` is configured through the `<servlet-mapping>` element in your `web.xml` deployment descriptor,
- `<path-info>` is the part usually used by Spring to perform its internal routing (unless `alwaysUseFullPath` is set on the `HandlerMapping`).

Therefore (theoretically) you should try accessing:

```
http://localhost:8080/projectName/spring-mvc-demo/
```

There is however another problem: your servlet mapping is an **exact** mapping, that does not match anything else beyond `/projectName/spring-mvc-demo`. You should replace it with a **prefix** mapping (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4140448/11748454) for an overview of servlet mappings):

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring-mvc-demo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you want to shorten your URL, the `DispatcherServlet` is usually mapped as default servlet `/`. Be aware **not** to use the catchall prefix mapping `/*`, which would override the mapping of the JSP servlet.

**Remark**: There are some cases when Spring does not use the part after `<servlet-path>` for its routing, e.g. when you use an exact or extension mapping, the whole path after `<context-path>` is used.

Therefore if you use:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring-mvc-demo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

you should specify:

```java
@RequestMapping("/spring-mvc-demo")
public String getMainMenu() {
   ...
}
```

and use the URL `http://localhost:8080/appName/spring-mvc-demo`.

Comment: I tried the url http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/spring-mvc-demo and could see blow error in server logs :

WARNING: No mapping for GET /spring-mvc-demo/spring-mvc-demo/ .

I am using spring-mvc-demo as my context-path since it is the name of my project.

Comment: Do you have a trailing slash? Since your requested mapping is `/` (with the servlet mapping in my answer) your should use `http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/spring-mvc-demo/` (with a trailing `/`). I forgot to mention: when you use **exact** servlet mappings, Spring behaves as if `alwaysUseFullPath` were enabled.