# How to solve "Can't accesss "\" 404 not found", as Package a spring project and deploy in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I use maven to package a spring boot project into a `ROOT.war` file. Then I remove all files under `tomcat/webapps/**` and move `ROOT.war` to this folder.

I run tomcat's `startup.h` script, and then I access the 8080 port, but it was any response.

If I simply start java project within this envirment, it can run correcttly, all services are good. But no response after deploying. Why?

I've tried these methods:

1. Exclude tomcat dependency.
2. Add maven configuration:

```html
   <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>com.godot.community.CommunityApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

### [404 Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSxbV.png)

#### 1. Project Overview

[All directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnK7S.png)

[Target Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0M98.png)

OS info

```bash
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/
```

#### 2.my `pom.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.godot.community</groupId>
    <artifactId>community</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>community</name>
    <description>godot community</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.29</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.spring.boot/mybatis-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.penggle/kaptcha -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.penggle</groupId>
            <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.alibaba/fastjson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qiniu/qiniu-java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qiniu</groupId>
            <artifactId>qiniu-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--TOMCAT error append  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>com.godot.community.CommunityApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

#### 3. Entry Function

> main func

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CommunityApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // Solve Netty start conflict problem (with redis)
        // see Netty4Utils.setAvailableProcessors
        System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CommunityApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(CommunityApplication.class);
    }

}
```

> controller

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController implements CommunityConstant {

    @Autowired
    private DiscussPostService discussPostService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private LikeService likeService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String root() {
        return "forward:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndexPage(Model model, Page page,
            @RequestParam(name = "orderMode", defaultValue = "0") int orderMode) {
......
```

#### 4. Deploy Script

`packageProject.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rm /tmp/community/** -rf
rm /community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/logs/** -rf

if [ $1 = "skip" ] ; then
    mvn clean package -D maven.test.skip=true -f /community/community
else
    mvn clean package -f /community/community
fi

rm /community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/webapps/* -rf
mv /community/community/target/ROOT.war /community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/webapps/

shutdown.sh
catalina.sh run
# startup.sh
```

#### 5. [Tomcat Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42cM3.png)

#### 6. `tomcat/conf/server.xml`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
     <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
     <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
     <!-- APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
     <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
     <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
     <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
     <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
     <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

     <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
     <GlobalNamingResources>
          <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
          <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
               type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
               description="User database that can be updated and saved"
               factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
               pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
     </GlobalNamingResources>

     <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
     <Service name="Catalina">

          <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
          <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


          <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
          <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
          <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
          <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
          <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
          <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

          <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
          <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

          <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

          <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
          <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
               <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
               <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

               <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
               <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
                    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                         resourceName="UserDatabase" />
               </Realm>

               <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
                    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                    <!-- <Context path="test" reloadable="true" docBase="../webapps/ROOT"></Context> -->
                    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
                    <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

                    <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                         prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
                         pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
               </Host>
          </Engine>
     </Service>
</Server>
```

#### 7. `tomcat/logs/catalina.*.log`

```
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.181 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.0.23
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 14 2022 08:16:11 UTC
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.0.23.0
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.192 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.193 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.194 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           17.0.3+7-Debian-1deb11u1
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.196 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Debian
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.221 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.224 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.226 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.227 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.227 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/conf/logging.properties
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.228 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.229 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.229 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.230 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/temp
14-Aug-2022 05:42:28.294 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
14-Aug-2022 05:42:29.368 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Aug-2022 05:42:29.521 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [2000] milliseconds
14-Aug-2022 05:42:29.721 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
14-Aug-2022 05:42:29.722 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.0.23]
14-Aug-2022 05:42:29.813 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/webapps/ROOT.war]
14-Aug-2022 05:46:25.181 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
14-Aug-2022 05:46:25.456 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/community/apache-tomcat-10.0.23/webapps/ROOT.war] has finished in [235,642] ms
14-Aug-2022 05:46:25.469 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Aug-2022 05:46:25.502 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [235979] milliseconds
```

#### 8. `/tmp/community/log_info.log` No info log generated

> Date not conform to the tomcat's

```
2022-08-14 05:25:41,974 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics [Metrics.java:663] Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
2022-08-14 05:25:41,975 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.m.Metrics [Metrics.java:669] Metrics reporters closed
2022-08-14 05:25:41,986 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#4-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser [AppInfoParser.java:83] App info kafka.consumer for consumer-community-consumer-group-3 unregistered
2022-08-14 05:25:41,998 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#4-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [LogAccessor.java:292] community-consumer-group: Consumer stopped
2022-08-14 05:25:42,011 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser [AppInfoParser.java:83] App info kafka.consumer for consumer-community-consumer-group-5 unregistered
2022-08-14 05:25:42,015 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [LogAccessor.java:292] community-consumer-group: Consumer stopped
2022-08-14 05:25:42,017 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser [AppInfoParser.java:83] App info kafka.consumer for consumer-community-consumer-group-1 unregistered
2022-08-14 05:25:42,024 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [LogAccessor.java:292] community-consumer-group: Consumer stopped
2022-08-14 05:25:42,025 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#3-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser [AppInfoParser.java:83] App info kafka.consumer for consumer-community-consumer-group-2 unregistered
2022-08-14 05:25:42,025 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#3-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [LogAccessor.java:292] community-consumer-group: Consumer stopped
2022-08-14 05:25:42,040 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.u.AppInfoParser [AppInfoParser.java:83] App info kafka.consumer for consumer-community-consumer-group-4 unregistered
2022-08-14 05:25:42,042 INFO [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer [LogAccessor.java:292] community-consumer-group: Consumer stopped
2022-08-14 05:25:42,055 INFO [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] o.s.s.q.SchedulerFactoryBean [SchedulerFactoryBean.java:847] Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2022-08-14 05:25:42,056 INFO [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] o.q.c.QuartzScheduler [QuartzScheduler.java:666] Scheduler communityScheduler_$_docker-desktop1660454728936 shutting down.
2022-08-14 05:25:42,056 INFO [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] o.q.c.QuartzScheduler [QuartzScheduler.java:585] Scheduler communityScheduler_$_docker-desktop1660454728936 paused.
2022-08-14 05:25:42,057 INFO [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] o.q.c.QuartzScheduler [QuartzScheduler.java:740] Scheduler communityScheduler_$_docker-desktop1660454728936 shutdown complete.
2022-08-14 05:25:42,316 INFO [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.z.h.HikariDataSource [HikariDataSource.java:350] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-08-14 05:25:42,373 INFO [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.z.h.HikariDataSource [HikariDataSource.java:352] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: Check the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa

Comment: More specific; spring boot 2.x requires Java EE which is only available up to Tomcat 9. Spring boot 3.x, which is currently in snapshot/pre-release stage is for Jakarta EE that is only available from Tomcat 10 and up. Have you tried to deploy this on Tomcat 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the problem is:

My spring boot version is 2.*. When I deploy this package in Tomcat-9.0.65. It works!

Thanks for @slindenau!

Answer (score 0):

pom.xml  add to

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```