# How to configure welcome file list in web.xml

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, welcome-file

I have this in my web.xml document. I am trying to have a welcome list so I dont need to type the path for the home page anymore. But everytime a clicked the application in my tomcat page it displays The requested resource is not available.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>web.Init</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>web.IndexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My servlet for the jsp page

```
package web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private RequestDispatcher jsp;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
        jsp = context.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp");
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        logger.debug("doGet()");
        jsp.forward(req, resp); 
    }
}
```

Why is that it is still not working?I still need to type the /index in my url...How to do this correctly?

Comment: what exactly are you entering in your URL , do you have an index.html page existing ??

Comment: For example I clicked my webapp in tomcat manager. It will display the url http://localhost:8080/myProj/ at the very first. So I still need to type the index after that url to open my welcome page. What wring with this?

Comment: your welcome file is [context root]/index.jsp  The servlet will not be called for the welcome page.

Comment: well @BalusC has given the complete answer , just follow it

Answer (score 62):

You need to put the JSP file in `/index.jsp` instead of in `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp`. This way the whole servlet is superflous by the way.

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml
 `-- index.jsp
```

If you're absolutely positive that you need to invoke a servlet this strange way, then you should map it on an URL pattern of `/index.jsp` instead of `/index`. You only need to change it to get the request dispatcher from `request` instead of from `config` and get rid of the whole `init()` method.

In case you actually intend to have a "home page servlet" (and thus **not** a welcome file — which has an entirely different purpose; namely the default file which sould be served when a *folder* is being requested, which is thus not specifically the root folder), then you should be mapping the servlet on the empty string URL pattern.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

See also [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern/).

Comment: You have it in `/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp` folder. You do not have it in root folder as `/index.jsp`. The anwer is to put it in the root folder, the same level as `/WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: I tried to change it but still the same problem. Resource is not available

Comment: Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart.

Comment: thank you for your response, this picture is right : )

Answer (score 24):

I guess what you want is your index servlet to act as the welcome page, so change to:

```
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So that the index servlet will be used.  Note, you'll need a servlet spec 2.4 container to be able to do this.

Note also, @BalusC gets my vote, for your index servlet on its own is superfluous.

Comment: I have servlet 3.1 and this still doesn't work for me. But making the webServlet annotation as empty like this @WebServlet("") works.What is the reason?

Answer (score 4):

I saw a nice solution in this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248473/change-default-homepage-in-root-path-to-servlet-with-doget) that may help the readers of the defulat servlet handling issue by using the empty string URL pattern "" :

```
@WebServlet("")
```

or

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourHomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern> <!-- Yes, empty string! -->
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my way to setup Servlet as welcome page.

I share for whom concern.

web.xml

```
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Demo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet class

```
@WebServlet(name = "/demo")
public class Demo extends HttpServlet {
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
     throws ServletException, IOException  {
       RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
   }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you need to call the servlet on load. Especially if you have your jsp under the WEB-INF folder which can't be reached directly.

Answer (score 0):

I simply declared as below in web.xml file and Its working for me :

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsps/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And NO html/jsp pages present in public directory except static resources(css, js, images).
Now I can access my index page with URL like :
http://localhost:8080/app/
Its calling  /WEB-INF/jsps/index.jsp page.  When hosted live in production the final URL looks like https://eisdigital.com/

Answer (score -2):

Its based on from which file you are trying to access those files.

If it is in the same folder where your working project file is, then you can use just the file name. no need of path.

If it is in the another folder which is under the same parent folder of your working project file then you can use location like in the following /javascript/sample.js

In your example if you are trying to access your js file from your html file you can use the following location

../javascript/sample.js

the prefix../ will go to the parent folder of the file(Folder upward journey)