# How to use a sub-folder as web.xml welcome directory

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, web.xml

I want to configure my web.xml for Google App Engine, but my configuration doesn't work. I want to change the default `index.html` with `WebApp/index.html`.

Here is the `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bg.app.AppServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>App</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WebApp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WebApp/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: I don't know what your _configuration doesn't work_ mean, but the `<welcome-file-list>` declaration needs to come before the `<servlet>` elements.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis it doesn't ;).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "welcome file" represents the physical file which needs to be served when a folder is requested by URL. E.g. `/` or `/WebApp/` or `WebApp/foo/`. It does not represent the "homepage file" or so as many starters seem to think. It does not make sense to let the welcome file point to a subfolder. It would fail when another subfolder is been requested.

Just stick to `index.html` as welcome file, put the desired homepage file in `/WebApp/` folder and create another `index.html` file in root folder `/` with the following content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Dummy homepage</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=WebApp" />
  </head>
</html>
```

This will redirect to `/WebApp/` (searchbots will treat it as 301) which in turn should serve the desired homepage file.

#### See also:

- [How to configure welcome file list in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648167/how-to-configure-welcome-file-list-in-web-xml/)
- [Set default home page via <welcome-file> in JSF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562813/set-default-home-page-via-welcome-file-in-jsf-project/)
- [Change default homepage in root path to servlet with doGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33248473/change-default-homepage-in-root-path-to-servlet-with-doget/)

Comment: This works great and has a big advantage over welcome-file-list in that the  URL in the address bar actually changes to what's specified in the meta tag above.