# Primefaces Poll component triggers HTTP OPTIONS and Ajax call is not made

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am writing a web app where homepage needs to refresh every second. I decided to use `Primefaces Poll` component to make ajax calls periodically.

However the call is not made on the project base url, such as:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

but it does work correctly, when the url describes the folder structure:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/index.xhtml
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

**Welcome-file in web.xml:**

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/web/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>    

    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{counterView.number}" id="counterNumber"/>
        <p:poll interval="1" listener="#{counterView.increment}" update="counterNumber"/>
    </h:form>    

</h:body>
</html>
```

**CounterView.java**

```
@Component("counterView")
@Scope("session")
public class CounterView {

    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void increment() {
        number++;
    }

}
```

Further debugging in FireBug shows that there's actually a **HTTP OPTIONS** method called:

[image]

But it's not even called to `http://localhost:8080/web/index.xhtml` but to `http://web/index.xhtml` and it's aborted after some time.

---

I could fix this problem by forcing a redirect to address `http://localhost:8080/web/index.xhtml` but I'd really like to know what's causing this problem and fix it more cleanly.

Comment: I think `<welcome-file>/web/index.xhtml</welcome-file>` doesn't need the first `/`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza WOW! Please write that as an answer, it really solves the problem. Now I can see where the problem was..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting an absolute path as your welcome file, this is noted by the first `/` in the value:

```xml
<welcome-file>/web/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

Remove it so it will be relative to the context path of your application:

```xml
<welcome-file>web/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
```

Comment: Please note that this is still not exactly the right way to use `<welcome-file>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425010/how-to-use-a-sub-folder-as-web-xml-welcome-directory