# Spring MVC using STS with tomcat devloader

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I created a Spring MVC web application following this tutorial:
http://www.journaldev.com/2433/spring-mvc-tutorial-for-beginners-with-spring-tool-suite

I am able to access it using the built-in server in the STS. Now, I want to deploy and test my web application using tomcat devloader plugin in eclipse. When I try to run it using tomcat I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Do you have any idea what may have cause this error and how to possibly solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have forgot to add some library to the bin.

Comment: What libraries should I be adding?

Comment: as per google spring-web.jar

Comment: I added that library now along with 3 other spring libraries namely, spring-beans,spring-context and spring-core. Now I get a different error:

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `spring-web.jar` from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE) and add it to the classpath. Also  just make sure your server classpath has included the Spring jar library.Also include [commons loggings.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonslogging111jar.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As you keep getting these `NoClassDefFoundError /CLassNotFound` exceptions try to copy the first line which is `'org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory'` and google it appending .jar at the very end. You will not know what jar to include.

Comment: I have added all the jars needed and there are no errors in running tomcat BUT I can't access my page. I always get HTTP Status 404.

Comment: check the url that you are trying. what is the project name? what is the .jsp/.html that you are trying and what the url?

Comment: In my tomcat settings, the context name is sme. I also added the directory as web root: /src/main/webapp. In the devloader settings, I checked all checkboxes. Then when I try to access localhost:8080/sme/ in the browser, I get Http 404 error. Then there is no stacktrace.

Comment: Do you have a starting page setup for your project ? drop a index.html in the root of your project in the tomcat and try localhost:8080/sme/index.html

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648167/how-to-configure-welcome-file-list-in-web-xml this welcomepage in web.xml if you dont want to mention the index.html. I think your project is setup properly.

Comment: When I am not using tomcat devloader, I can view my webapp in the browser without any errors. It is most likely that my project was not loaded properly in the devloader.

Comment: You should add the project to the devloader by right clicking on the tomcat server > add project