# Default Jsp in Spring mvc 4

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In Spring mvc how we can set a default jsp page i.e., as soon as we run the project on server a default jsp page should show up in the browser, just like in jsf we can achieve it using below code in web.xml :

```
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is same in spring also ,

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/abc.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

you can set in the `web.xml`.but you should have `abc.jsp` outside the `web-inf` to make it visible to the browser.

**see also :**

- [How to configure welcome file list in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648167/how-to-configure-welcome-file-list-in-web-xml)

Comment: Its giving 404 error, with a description "The requested resource is not available."
I have put all my jsps under pages folder inside WEB_INF, but index.jsp is inside WEB-INF only

Comment: NO  . you cant access the `index` file directly from the `web-inf` . put it inside the `web pages` to display it as welcome page. other pages you can have it inside the `web-inf` as it will be intercepted with dispatcher-servlet

Comment: you mean to say that my default welcome file should be inside web content and the rest I can put it inside WEB_INF and the path of these I can get it from controller, right???

Answer (score 0):

While using spring also u can mention the same in web.xml

```
   <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding default controller pointing to index.jsp?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
public String index() {
   return "index";
}
```

p.s. Did you specified a view resolver?

Comment: <bean id="viewresolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/Pages/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
   <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
This is what I wrote in my dispatcher-servlet.xml and the same code I tried which you are suggesting but I don't know why it's not working

Comment: This will work in case your index.jsp is located in /WEB-INF/Pages directory as view-resolver will  lookup pages placed in aforementioned folder.

Comment: Maybe welcome-file -list tag was also there in web.xml so it was conflicting..and as soon as I removed it, this one is working too. Thanks :)