# Route 53: Redirecting to EC2 + application context

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

So I've registered a domain name www.abc.com that points to my EC2 instance 1.2.3.4

On this EC2 instance I've a Tomcat application called my-application. I can access the application via invoking http://1.2.3.4/my-application

I've configured www.abc.com to point to 1.2.3.4

But now how do I configure it to redirect to http://1.2.3.4/my-application instead?

What concept does this involve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not EC2 issue, please specify your tomcat to show my-application as the welcome-page.  See below:

- [How to configure welcome file list in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648167/how-to-configure-welcome-file-list-in-web-xml/)

After that, you can publish your application on `http://1.2.3.4:8080/my-application`.

Then, you need to redirect `http://1.2.3.4:80` to `http://1.2.3.4:8080/my-application`

There are two methods:

- Use Reverse Proxy (ex: Use nginx or apache web server as proxy)
- Use AWS Application Load Balancing (if you use this pattern, you need to configure A record for Route53. From my wildly guessing, you already configure CNAME for Route53.)