# 404 Not Found No context found for request

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As you can see the image below, My HTML index page is at static folder. How can I point localhost to `static/index.html`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9veL.png]

Tried on my own on basic hello world.

```
static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler { 
    public void 
    handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException { 
    String response = "Hello world"; 
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length()); 
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        os.write(response.getBytes()); os.close(); 
} 
}
```

I need to know how I can point the default localhost:8080 to my pre-built existing static/index.html page?

Answer (score 0):

If I may have understood ur question correctly on the start up of your  application you want to display your page as a default page
please go through below link

[How to configure welcome file list in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648167/how-to-configure-welcome-file-list-in-web-xml/)

This will let you know how to configure your web.xml page to let tomcat or any other web container to know your default page.

you may try this

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/welcomePage", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is the response";
            // we do not set content type, headers, cookies etc.
        // resp.setContentType("text/html"); // while redirecting as
        // it would most likely result in an IllegalStateException

        // "/" is relative to the context root (your web-app name)
        RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/file.html");
        // don't add your web-app name to the path

        view.forward(req, resp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there no tomcat. im running main()

Comment: i dont see any web.xml in the project hosted in github also

Comment: I guess U may  bind it a default context of "/" for default home page.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Please let me know is it works for you. Else we may find a better way.

Comment: are you saying you are unable to import RequestDispatcher class ?