# How to remove whole context from the URL in tomcat 8

Tags: java, xml, server, tomcat8

I want to remove the whole context from the url.

I have already tried the ROOT.war method for removing the war

Let's say my url is ---https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

After applying the ROOT.war method i am still getting this--https://stackoverflow.com/ask

I want my url like this ---https://stackoverflow.com

How can i achieve this in Tomcat 8 version

Comment: What are you exposing at `/ask`? A servlet?

Comment: i am using /login page (jsp file)

Comment: IIRC, welcome page configuration can be leveraged here

Comment: Then it can't be `/ask`, I suppose. You could try to set that jsp as welcome page.

Comment: are there any other `war`s deployed in server ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question 100% but can't you do a redirect?

Comment: @casper sorry i can do a redirect

Comment: @himanshu can u explain this welcome page i think it can help?

Comment: @ernest same for you can u elaborte this welcome page?

Comment: @jagpreetsingh Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648360/5761558 Just change from `index` to `login.jsp` (or whatever your jsp name is).

Answer (score 0):

You are right. You can remove context-root when you rename your *.war file to ROOT.war. What you are talking about is to remove "/ask" from url. It has nothing common with tomcat. In your project you have to set your request to "/" and not to "/ask" . In spring-boot you can set with annotation 
`@GetMapping("/ask") public Greeting sayHello ()`and it means that when you write in browser https://stackoverflow.com/ask then request go into this method. But when you want to reach the same result but without "/ask" you can write `@GetMapping("/ask")` . Depends on which framework you are using and there you have to setup this options to redirect request to "/"